# Help with 301 redirect (Simple concept, per directory control)

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to get a set of 301 redirects working for a client site, and I'm getting a bit stuck.

I have about 17 different directories that have .html content fileswhich I am moving across to Wordpress. What I am trying to do is create a simple, single .htaccess file with redirects in that will allow me to redirect all the .html files within a directory to wordpress URLs without an extension:

Manual redirect example:

redirect 301 /blog/2009/04/post1.html /blog/2009/04/post1/
redirect 301 /blog/2009/04/post2.html /blog/2009/04/post2/

Trying to create a rule like:

RewriteRule ^/blog/2009/04/(.*?).html$ /blog/2009/04/$1/ [R=301,NC,L]

Where the $1 is the filename (minus the .html) suffixed with a /

I can't determine whether the ^/blog/2009/04/(.*?).html$ means it will only redirect for this particular directory, and will redirect to the right location.

I would obviously want to duplicate this ReWriteRule for all my designated content directories...

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your rule will only redirect for the `2009/04` directory. I think you want:

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*?).html$ /blog/$1/$2/$3/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

This will now also redirect `/blog/2008/12/post.html` to `/blog/2008/12/post/` and so on. Although since you have almost exactly the same format, maybe this will be easier?

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/(.*?).html$ /blog/$1/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Will I be able to use something like:
RewriteRule ^/services/(.*?).html$ /services/$1/ [R=301,NC,L]
For non-blog directories?

Comment: Yes, if the bit in `(.*?)` will be the same as where you put the `$1`.